# android one button click two time automatic

Tags: android

I created an app working with printer wireless connection and do print. When I click on button It'll be print only 1 time. I want to print one more time after clicked. So it's mean when I clicks 1 time and 5 seconds later this button will be click automatic without my click again. Below of my code it's working but non stop. I want after 2 time process it'll stop thread. Do you have any solution please help. Thanks. Below is my code:

```
public void buttonPrintClicked(){
    buttonPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonPrintGotClick();
        }
    });
}

// Do something when button print was click
private void buttonPrintGotClick(){

    int noOfSecond = 5;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Set button auto perform click.
            buttonPrint.performClick();

            // Close current Activity
            get_order_Activity.this.finish();
        }
    }, noOfSecond * 500);

    // Delete Previous PDF file first before create new again
    deleteFileFromStorage();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(get_order_Activity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(linearLayout_PDF, linearLayout_PDF.getWidth(), linearLayout_PDF.getHeight());
    createPdf();

    // Open File from Storage
    openFileFromStorage();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put `postDelayed` in `onClick` callback. Here is my edited code.

```
public void buttonPrintClicked(){
    buttonPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonPrintGotClick();
            int noOfSecond = 5;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    buttonPrintGotClick();
                    get_order_Activity.this.finish();
                }
            }, noOfSecond * 500);

        }
    });
}

// Do something when button print was click
private void buttonPrintGotClick(){
    // Delete Previous PDF file first before create new again
    deleteFileFromStorage();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(get_order_Activity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(linearLayout_PDF, linearLayout_PDF.getWidth(), linearLayout_PDF.getHeight());
    createPdf();
    // Open File from Storage
    openFileFromStorage();
}
```

Comment: One answer correct direction. It's perfect working. Thanks!